# MongoDB sharded cluster, behavior when balancer is off?

Tags: database, mongodb, distributed, sharding, bson

Currently using 4.2.8 community edition. Have a sharded cluster with 20+ shard nodes.

If I turn off the balancer, will inserted documents still be distributed to the correct shard nodes -- assuming a good shard key has been utilized? I believe i have chosen a good hashed key, and the data seems to get distributed well already, however, I'm experiencing some slow-downs in insert speed during peak traffic.

I would like to only allow the balancer to run during scheduled times in the day to maximize my cluster's performance but I don't know if that means that all the inserts will just go to the primary shard and max out the disk. Can someone clarify?

Comment: There is also https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-sharded-cluster-balancer/#schedule-the-balancing-window.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your data will be inserted into appropriate shard.

However, when your shard-key is properly chosen then the balancer will be idle most of the time anyway. So, I don't see any reason to disable the balancer unless you have to run some maintenance or upgrade.

Check the balancer status when you see slow-downs in insert speed during peak traffic, then you see whether the balancer could be the culprit.

There is a build-in function (thanks to @D. SM), see [Schedule the Balancing Window](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-sharded-cluster-balancer/#schedule-the-balancing-window)

> In some situations, particularly when your data set grows slowly and a
> migration can impact performance, it is useful to ensure that the
> balancer is active only at certain times. The following procedure
> specifies the activeWindow, which is the timeframe during which the
> balancer will be able to migrate chunks